# Batch timer that can open multiple applications at once

Tags: batch-file

For a program I'm working on I need to open the same executable numerous times, so I thought that it would be way more easy to make a batch file that opens enough applications up automatically. I've tried 2 different methods and both give problems, I'll copy and paste the code here and explain what excactly goes wrong:

Code 1:

```
for /l %%x in (1, 1, 6) do (
   echo %%x

   start test.exe
)

exit
```

Here I try to open up 6 of the same applications immidiatly, and even if this works close to perfect, some of the applications ask to overwrite files in the windows temp folder, and while it's easy to just say now and get it to work that way, it isn't really user friendly

I thought that if I put a some time between opening a new application (1-5 ms) this problem wouldn't happen, so that got me to make another attempt.

Code 2:

```
SET n=0
:Loop
SET /A n=n+1
test.exe
Ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 10
if %n% EQU 6 (
  exit
) Else if %n% LEQ 3 (
  Goto Loop
)

exit
```

Somehow, this program doesn't let me open up multiple applications at once, if I want another application to be started, I need to end the one that is running, and for my project I really need multiple applications started up at once.

Can somebody please help me out with this?

PS: If you're interested in what I'm doing, here's a link to my forum post about it: https://forum.yoyogames.com/index.php?threads/multi-exe-communications.852/

Comment: I already fixed it, still many thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `start` command to launch the executable:

```
start test.exe
```

This will launch the process without waiting on it to terminate before continuing.

Comment: Many thanks, I can't believe that I didn't see that!